# Got a unsupported operand error when I'm trying to overwrite the __plus__ function

Tags: python, overwrite

I'm trying to learn OOP in Python, and making the following code to overwrite the `__plus__` method

```
class Fraction(object):
    '''Define a fraction type'''
    def __init__(self, num=0, denom=1):
        '''Create a new Fraction with numerator num and denominator demon'''
        self.numerator = num
        if denom != 0:
            self.denominator = denom
        else:
            raise ZeroDivisionError


    def __plus__(self, f):
        num = self.numerator + f.numerator      
        denom = self.numerator + f.denominator
        return "{0}/{1}".format(num, denom)

f = Fraction(1, 6)
```

print f + f # I want to result be 2/12

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Fraction'
```

but it gives me an error, I don't know how to solve the error, any idea?

Comment: Probably you want `__add__` interface?

Comment: Two points: (1) `__add__` should probably return a `Fraction` instance, not a string.  (2) `a/b + c/d` isn't generally equal to `(a+b)/(c+d)`, so your arithmetic doesn't quite work.

Comment: `from fractions import Fraction`

Comment: @DSM You are right, especially about the second point, it returns an Fraction instance make more sense, for OOP concept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override the `__add__` method instead of `__plus__`. Just try to replace `__plus__` with `__add__`.

Answer (score 1):

Working code:

```
class Fraction(object):
    '''Define a fraction type'''
    def __init__(self, num=0, denom=1):
        '''Create a new Fraction with numerator num and denominator demon'''
        self.numerator = num
        if denom != 0:
            self.denominator = denom
        else:
            raise ZeroDivisionError

    def __add__(self, f):
        num = self.numerator + f.numerator      
        denom = self.denominator + f.denominator
        return "{0}/{1}".format(num, denom)
```

Notice that I also fixed `denom = self.denominator + f.denominator`